# How to navigate between jsp pages

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-inf

I have a jsp page called `home.jsp` outside the WEB-INF directory and an other `jsp` page called `service.jsp` inside the `WEB-INF` folder. I need to put this `service.jsp` page inside the `WEB-INF` directory so it cannot be accessible if a user attempts to get access to it by typing its URL. So my problem is how can i navigate from `home.jsp` to `service.jsp` with click on button in the `home.jsp` Thank you.

Comment: If you put home.jsp as well in WEB-INF folder that whats the problem here?

Comment: if i put home.jsp inside web-inf as well i get an http error saying Problem accessing /service.jsp while calling service.jsp with this line in home.jsp <button type="button"  onclick="location.href='service.jsp'">Start Uploading</button>

Comment: your page is demo/WEB-INF/pages/yourPage.jsp
create a page demo/yourPage.jsp
Source Code:
view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

<%@ include file="WEB-INF/pages/yourPage.jsp" %>

Comment: So, you want to access to a JSP that you deliberately put inside WEB-INF to make it inaccessible? Isn't it quite contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

You should use forward to access the file under WEB-INF.
There are two methods for you to choose:
1.look like this :

```
 <!--  /test/test2.jsp  outside WEB-INF -->
<html>
<body>
<form name="testform">
<jsp:forward page = "/WEB-INF/jsp/test/test.jsp" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2.use struts to forward

```
<action path="/test" type=" test.TestAction" scope="request"> 
<forward name="test" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/test/test.jsp"/> 
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

why is it contradictory ? i want my application to access to that file and keep it away from reach by typing a simple URL.
I finally found what i have to do.
I created a servlet let's say serviceServlet.java in which i include this line in the doGet() method:

```
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB INF/service.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

This line will forward my request to the service.jsp file under WEB-INF.

Next step i defined in my web.xml a url pattern to redirect to that servlet when clicking a button say /service like this

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>serviceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.CloudUploadserviceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serviceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And ultimately in the home.jsp file i included this line in the onClick method to call the servlet:

```
   onclick="location.href='/service'"
```

And it's done :)